# Disjoint union of cycles

Tags: graph-theory

> Prove that every 2-regular graph is isomorphic to a disjoint Union of cycles.

What does a disjoint Union of cycles mean?

And how is it isomorphic to a 2-regular graph?

I'm new to graph theory, I understand what a 2-regular graph is and what isomorphism is. I don't understand how they connect since I don't understand what a disjoint Union of cycles would mean.

Comment: Do you know what disjoint means? Do you know what union means? Do you know what cycle means? It'd be unnecessary to say it's isomorphic to a 2-regular graph. One would just say it *is* a 2-regular graph. Although you are probably repeating some statement you heard saying it the other way around: every 2-regular graph is a disjoint union of cycles.

Comment: What question? You haven't quoted any question. Should we assume the question is "Prove every 2-regular graph is a disjoint union of cycles?"

Comment: yes I understand what the 3 terms mean. However, I don't understand what the mean together. Should I assume they're talking about cyclic graphs disconnected or each cyclic graph separately. And yes, my apologies, I framed the question incorrectly.

Comment: We mean every 2-regular graph is a disjoint union of subgraphs each of which is a cycle.

Comment: i have refined the question.

Comment: In your edit, you deleted all of your personal commentary, which has turned it into a command directed at the community (a community which doesn't like being ordered to do people's homework for them). The word for this is PSQ ("problem statement question"). In order to ask a good question, you need to actually *talk* to us, which included telling us what you know and what you don't understand, what you've tried etc.

Comment: But you didn't like how it was framed. So I simply edited it. I'm not trying to command anything. Just needed help to understand the problem!

Comment: You didn't "simply" edit it, you **deleted** all of your personal commentary. If you were a teacher and a student came into your office, slapped a textbook exercise in front of you and pointed at it without saying a word, would you consider that polite human interaction? No. (People doesn't generally consider discussion in the comment thread to count.) You can state what the original problem was *and* communicate with us, they aren't mutually exclusive. Sorry if this is sounding harsh and new to you, I don't want to scare you but you'll encounter these issues sooner or later on MSE.

Comment: Okay I understand. I see you've edited it back to the original question and added the refined version already. So thank you! I'll keep this is mind next time. Really not trying to be rude. Thanks for your explanation. It helps.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you encountered a problem saying "Prove every 2-regular graph is a disjoint union of cycles" and talk about that.

Suppose a finite graph is 2-regular. Pick a vertex. It has two edges. Follow along one of those edges to get another vertex. That vertex is connected by another edge to another vertex. And so on. In this way we get a sequence of vertices each determined by the previous one.

Eventually, since there are only finitely many vertices, this sequence of vertices must repeat itself, and so we've gone in a circle. In other words, we've found a *cycle* within the graph. And this cycle includes a pair of edges for every vertex, which means there are no other edges connecting these vertices to anything outside the cycle. In other words, this cycle is *disjoint* from the rest of the graph.

Then we can move this known cycle to the side and repeat the process over and over again with the rest of the graph until we've encountered every vertex. In this way, we see that the graph is a bunch of cycle graphs that are all disjoint from each other.

For example, here is a 2-regular graph with 15 vertices:

$\hskip 1in$ [image: cycles]